# Is there a way to get which site was used from azure for a direct line connection for a chatbot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

In my chatbot, I have a direct line connection.  Recently, I have been given the requirement to create a new direct line site for another project.  Is there a way to get the direct line site name in my c# code? I want to have the code run different code paths based on the direct line site name.

In my azure chatbot resource group I have the direct line connection and I have two sites. The chatbot is hooked into 2 different websites using the direct line connection

Site 1. InternalUsers
Site 2. ExternalUsers

I would like to see which site the bot is being called from

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but you can set up an event handler for webchat join events to pass values from your source page to the bot. Within the code to deploy the bot on the web, I have the following section:

```js
              if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                  dispatch.dispatch({
                    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                    payload: {
                      name: 'webchat/join',
                      value: {
                        browserLanguage: navigator.languages[0],
                        page: window.location.href,
                        language: getCookie("LANGUAGE"),
                        country: getCookie("COUNTRYNAME"),
                        uid: getCookie("uid")
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
```

You can put whatever values within the payload that you need, perhaps site name in your case. Then create or add to your onEvent handler something like

```js
if (context.activity.name && context.activity.name === 'webchat/join') {
    const userData = await this.userDialogStateAccessor.get(context, {});
    userData.siteContext = context.activity.value;
    
    // Additional code if needed

    await this.userState.saveChanges(context);
```

If you just need to reference these values later, your event handler can just save them to user state and move on. You can also create a customEvent for App Insights or whatever logging application you are using, which is probably required if you want to report on this. I also use mine for targeted welcome messages based on whether we authenticated the customer from the initiating site. The message is sent from within onEvent, though I also have the "standard" welcome message that comes from the onMembersAdded handler (which has a condition of only being invoked for non-directline channels).

Once you have that value in user state, you can use that to drive different bot behavior, such as calling different dialogs based on the site, or having variable behavior within a dialog.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, please consider accepting and upvoting this answer so that others can find it.